# interdiscplinary phd communication

Tags: phd, advisor, communication, interdisciplinary

An engineer (me), a mathematician and a social psychologist (my supervisors) walked into a bar and decided to do a PhD project together. How do the three ensure that they do not have communication issues?

Each field comes with its own peculiar jargon and perspective. How does one achieve efficient communication while at the same time being true to their own discipline?

(we work in building dynamical models of human behaviour, the topic requires expertise from all three disciplines).

Comment: This is a really broad question. There are simply too many potential pitfalls in an interdisciplinary collaboration. Can you narrow your question to some more specific scenarios?